# Should not be the same a glm with family-link function gaussian(log) that a lm with log(outcome) ~ ...?

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I am using the R package `lme4` and for a certain data set and formula of the form `outcome ~ ...`, if I try `glmer(formula, family = gaussian(link = "log"), data = dataset)` I get an error

```
Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L,  : 
  Downdated VtV is not positive definite
```

Meanwhile, if I try `lmer(log(outcome) ~ ..., data = dataset)` I get a clear output. I thought both instructions were equivalent. Which is the difference and which could be the reason for the error?

Comment: Using a log link and log transforming the response are not equivalent. See, e.g, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47840/linear-model-with-log-transformed-response-vs-generalized-linear-model-with-log) for some discussion.  I don't know the reason for the problems with the model with the log link; you might add some data to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the link.